has the meaning (of) "otherwise"

According to this dictionary, "Hurry up, or you'll be late" could be
paraphrased as "Hurry up. Otherwise, you'll be late". But, that does
not mean that "or" on its own has the meaning of "otherwise".

Should I remove of or retain it?

With identifications like the quotation marks or italic font for otherwise, the sentence can  do without of:

But that does not mean that "or" on its own has the meaning "otherwise".

Here otherwise is the complement of meaning.  It is a word, a noun, rather than a normal adverb.
Of would be needed if there are no such identifications; this would be unclear:

*But that does not mean that "or" on its own has the meaning otherwise.


Now I can rest assured that of is optional. Thank you very much, Seowjooheng Singapore.

You're welcome, @Kaguyahime.
